# Request multi column min/max with date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, minmax

I have a SQL table which look like :

```
Date        temp    dewpoint    humidity
10/12/15    5.1     2.4         57
11/12/15    4.1     5.8         69
12/12/15    20.6    3.6         56
13/12/15    13.0    2.5         21
14/12/15    5.6     13.6        15
15/12/15    5.1     2.4         56
```

I would like to know it it's possible to print this out with only one SQL query. That is for each data column, get the min and max value with the occurrence date (As an example I would like to know that the min 4.1 was on 11/12/15 and the max was 20.6 on 12/12/15.)

Would it be possible to do this with one sql query? Specifically, I want the output format as:

```
Date        dataName     dataValue
11/12/15    temp-min     4.1
12/12/15    temp-max     20.6
14/12/15    humidity-min 15
11/12/15    humidity-max 69
```

Comment: Note that dates in sql adhere to a specific format

Comment: If the min value occurs on two or more dates, what should happen?

Comment: If the min occurs on more than one date, having the last date would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way is probably to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(date order by temp asc), ',', 1) as minTempDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(date order by temp desc), ',', 1) as maxTempDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(date order by dewpoint asc), ',', 1) as minDPDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(date order by dewpoint desc), ',', 1) as maxDPDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(date order by humidity asc), ',', 1) as minHumidityDate,
       substring_index(group_concat(date order by humidity desc), ',', 1) as maxHumidityDate
from table t;
```

An alternative is to use `union all` like this:

```
(select date, 'temp-min', temp from table t order by temp asc limit 1)
union all
(select date, 'temp-max', temp from table t order by temp desc limit 1)
union all
(select date, 'humidity-min', humidity from table t order by humidity asc limit 1)
union all
(select date, 'humidity-max', humidity from table t order by humidity desc limit 1)
```

Comment: group_concat comes with a caveat in the form of group_concat_max_len. upd: but in this particular case i guess it doesn't matter

Comment: Thank for your proposal ! The first solution give me only dates, but no values... I need both !

Your second proposal seem to meet my requirement... In first approach, it seems to be a bit more efficient than the solution given by Marc B.

Comment: @removebeforeflight . . . In the first approach, you could add `min(temp)`, `max(temp)`, and so on.  However, you want the results in different rows, so the second method seems preferable -- unless you have lots and lots of columns.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what you want to receive, but it's looks terrible.

```
SELECT date, 'temp-min' dataName, temp dataValue
FROM numbers WHERE temp = (SELECT min(temp) FROM numbers)
UNION
SELECT date, 'temp-max' dataName, temp dataValue
FROM numbers WHERE temp = (SELECT max(temp) FROM numbers)
UNION
SELECT date, 'humidity-min' dataName, humidity dataValue
FROM numbers WHERE humidity = (SELECT min(humidity) FROM numbers)
UNION
SELECT date, 'humidity-max' dataName, humidity dataValue
FROM numbers WHERE humidity = (SELECT max(humidity) FROM numbers)
;
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks you for your suggestion. It seems to work, but if I have the same max (or min) value on several dates, I get all dates... so, I need to add an extra filter. Solution given by Gordon Linoff give only one record par min/max (and seems to be a little more efficient than your).

I keep your suggestion if I would like to get all days the maximum value was reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it trivially with a single query:

```
SELECT Date, max(temp), min(temp), max(dewpoint), min(dewpoint), etc...
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Date
```

to get a multi-column result of your min/maxes. But in MySQL it is difficult to "unpivot" that result into a single column/multi-row result. That kind of transformation is better done in client-side code.

Comment: This would not work.. This would give you the min/max value for each column for each day, not across all days with correlation to dates on which those min/max occurred.

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't meet my requirement (it give min/Max for each date).